# Create Jar files without main class in Junit5/gradle project

Tags: java, jar, junit5

How to create a jar file for a gradle project /Junit Intellij IDE which doesn't have main class? Tests are called through use JunitPlatform from gradle.

Is there any way to call tests from main class using in JUnit5? like programmatically launch the test from java main class. so that I can create the jar file.

Comment: Do you need an executable jar file or Just a jar which contains classes?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking; what's a "main class"? Why do you want to "launch the test" from the "main class"? What are you asking?

Answer (score 0):

For special purposes it is possible to launch the JUnit Platform programmatically using the `Launcher` API.

You can of course do this from a `main()` method if you so desire.

This is documented in the [JUnit 5 User Guide](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#launcher-api).